# Hazelcast Map Stats

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to display statistic of a map. It always showing no of hits as 0. I am using the following code.

```
IMap<String, byte[]> map = Hazelcast.getMap("SOMEMAP");
LocalMapStatsImpl local = (LocalMapStatsImpl) map.getLocalMapStats();
System.out.println(map.getLocalMapStats());
```

and the output is

```
LocalMapStatsImpl{ownedEntryCount=0, backupEntryCount=1, markedAsRemovedEntryCount=0, ownedEntryMemoryCost=0, backupEntryMemoryCost=13841, markedAsRemovedMemoryCost=0, creationTime=1323806943770, lastAccessTime=0, lastUpdateTime=0, lastEvictionTime=0, hits=0, lockedEntryCount=0, lockWaitCount=0, dirtyEntryCount=0, LocalMapOperationStats{total= 0, puts:OperationStat{count=0, averageLatency=0}, gets:OperationStat{count=0, verageLatency=0}, emoves:OperationStat{count=0, averageLatency=0}, others: 0, received events: 0}}
```

Any help is appreciated. I want to know the no of hits, size of the map and entry count.

Comment: any help .... ? Its  urgent for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download hazelcast-monitor9.3.4.jar and install in it your local apache webserver. Access the web application. It will launch a login page. Just provide the cluster name, password and server:port  and click connect. It will display all the maps with statistic.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you put some entries into map. As seen from stats you have only one entry in the map and that entry is owned by another node, current node has backup of that entry (ownedEntryCount=0, backupEntryCount=1).

Notice that this statistics are only for current nodes local map. If you have more than one node and current node does not own any data  at the time you get the stats then you will get 0 for no of hits or owned entry count.

Using Hazelcast 1.9.4.4 (latest as of now) and single node, I can get the stats by;

```
IMap map = Hazelcast.getMap("test");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    map.put(i, i);
    map.get(i);
}
LocalMapStats stats = map.getLocalMapStats();
System.err.println(stats.getHits());
System.err.println(stats.getOwnedEntryCount());
```

Both hits and ownedEntryCount show 100.

```
LocalMapStatsImpl{ownedEntryCount=100, backupEntryCount=0, markedAsRemovedEntryCount=0, ownedEntryMemoryCost=42100, backupEntryMemoryCost=0, markedAsRemovedMemoryCost=0, creationTime=1323844949878, lastAccessTime=1323844949908, lastUpdateTime=0, lastEvictionTime=0, hits=100, lockedEntryCount=0, lockWaitCount=0, dirtyEntryCount=0, LocalMapOperationStats{total= 200, puts:OperationStat{count=100, averageLatency=0}, gets:OperationStat{count=100, averageLatency=0}, removes:OperationStat{count=0, averageLatency=0}, others: 0, received events: 0}}
```

Try this and see if you will get the same results. Otherwise either your map is empty or there is a bug in version you have used.

Comment: I tried it it still show wrong results. I am using 1.9.3.4. One thing i observed is when i call Hazelcast.getMap in my standalone program it will create a new entry with some other port number and this map gets attached to it. And the results of this map are shown. I can see it clearly using the hazelcast monitor running in local apache. How do i get the same port where i see the actual map entries.

Comment: Hazelcast.getMap (and also other static 'get' methods of Hazelcast class) is used to access static/default instance on Classloader/JVM. If there is not already then a new one is created lazily. To access local statistics of an HazelcastInstance, you should call getMap() and getLocalMapStats() on that specific instance. You can not access stats of an instance directly using another HazelcastInstance. But there are indirect ways of accessing, like submitting remote task or using Hazelcast ManagementCenter.